# Wpf dispatcher.invoke hung

Tags: c#, wpf, message-queue, invoke, dispatcher

I have a large WPF app with few threads ( all threads use dispatcher.invoke to update the GUI) and many grids and controls. At any give time only 2 or three grids are visible so the user can interact with the controls. I also have an external device which sends a signal to my app and I then update the GUI so the user knows the signal was fired.

I do the update through a dispatcher since the signal detection is on another thread. So everything is fine until intermittently it takes 5 minutes for the dispatcher.invoke with normal priority to call my method. when this happens as soon as I click the GUI then method gets called immediately. So it seems that message pump is asleep or hung and as soon as I click on the GUI it wakes up and process my message. I have done this several times so I am sure that message queue wakes up upon refreshing the GUI.

So is this a bug in WPF message pump queue where it occasionally goes to sleep and wakes up when the GUI is refreshed? or what is the reason for this behavior and what to do about it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're only updating the GUI from your threads, why not use BeginInvoke?

Comment: I cannot I need to update the GUI before I can move on to other tasks.

Comment: I'd still try to avoid waiting on the GUI thread in your background threads. Generally it's not a very good practice. I think you better show the relevant code if you want to get help. It's just speculations without anything concrete to see.